# communication between express + angularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, angularjs

with angularJS i have got a datafile, where i communicate with the database.

Therefore i want to send the data to the i got from the frontend to send it to the packend, but somehow this is now working. can you please help me.

```
app.get('/api/data/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.json({...});
});

app.post('/api/data/', function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        success: true
    })
});
```

for the get and delete functions this works fine, but I have no idea how to make the post and put function and how to get the data in there.

Here what i do on the client

```
        add:function (data) {
            location = '/api/data/';
            $http.put(location, merchant, successCb).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(arguments);
                    successCb(data);
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('Error:' + arguments);
                });
        },
```

can someone please help me how to write that on the server and client. (i get the right data on the client and its a simple javascript object.

Comment: What DB system do you use ? If you'd show us what you do in get, it could help also.
If you want to use MongoDB for instance, you can read this : http://www.pixelhandler.com/blog/2012/02/09/develop-a-restful-api-using-node-js-with-express-and-mongoose/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use $resource which is the correct way for communicating with restful server side data source...

angularjs has very nice examples about $resource here:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource